# Are local variables available in child function?

Tags: recursion, coldfusion, scope

I have written a ColdFusion UDF which calls itself recursively. What I would like to know is whether local/var scoped variables set in a parent call to the function are available in the child function or whether they are only available in the function call where they were set.

I am away from my workstation for a while so am unable to test for myself so wondered if anybody already knew the answer to this.

Thanks!

Comment: I suspect not.  Let us know how it turns out when you get back to your workstation and try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function-local variables are local to the *current* call to that function. Each function call has its own memory space, and function local variables reside in that memory space. Recursive calls are no different in this regard.

As far as I know, JavaScript is no different here: I'd like to see an example that bears out your assertion that it's different.

Comment: You're right about JavaScript too ([http://jsfiddle.net/unJ3x/](http://jsfiddle.net/unJ3x/)), I don't know why I thought it was different. I've edited my question to reflect this. Thanks!